# Can I select alternative class features when mutliclassing?

Tags: dnd-4e, multi-classing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to get Battle Cleric's Lore through Divine Healer multiclass?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9325/is-it-possible-to-get-battle-clerics-lore-through-divine-healer-multiclass)

A person with Healer's Lore can take an alternative Battle Cleric's Lore.

Can someone who has Divine Healer [Cleric multiclass], which gives them Healer's Lore take the same alternative?